# How to maintain or retrieve cache access token of LinkedIn in ios

Tags: ios, api, linkedin-api, access-token

I don't know how to maintain OAuth access token and Consumer key of LinkedIn. I got connection list when i always login with linkedIn only, that token is maintaining.

Like facebook, how to maintain access token and used to get the connection list. Below is my code. Here i know, i am oAuthLoginView.Consumer, this information is getting from after login the Login view. But if we don't want to login all the time. In this case how to maintain and pass. I tried some more ways. I did not get solution.

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:   (id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,positions:(company))
    OAMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                    consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                       token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                    callback:nil
                           signatureProvider:nil];

```
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(friendsApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

Can i get correction Solution. Thanks.

Comment: What did you mean when you said "how to maintain OAuth access token and Consumer key of LinkedIn"? Are you asking about storing those in DB and using them later for api calls?

Comment: Yes, how to store them in DB.

Comment: Are you having trouble in getting access tokens? Or you got them already?

Comment: I got the access token, but i don't know how to save in DB